# why is ngRepeat not working on this json object

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I got this json object returned from a http restful

```
[
    {
        "person": {
            "id": 1,
            "fullName": "A person # 1",
            "age": 7
        }
    },
    {
        "person": {
            "id": 2,
            "fullName": "A person # 2",
            "age": 22
        }
    },
    {
        "person": {
            "id": 3,
            "fullName": "A person # 3",
            "age": 34
        }
    },
    {
        "person": {
            "id": 4,
            "fullName": "A person # 4",
            "age": 25
        }
    },
    {
        "person": {
            "id": 5,
            "fullName": "A person # 5",
            "age": 17
        }
    },
    {
        "person": {
            "id": 6,
            "fullName": "A person # 6",
            "age": 4
        }
    },
    {
        "person": {
            "id": 7,
            "fullName": "A person # 7",
            "age": 30
        }
    },
    {
        "person": {
            "id": 8,
            "fullName": "A person # 8",
            "age": 7
        }
    },
    {
        "person": {
            "id": 9,
            "fullName": "A person # 9",
            "age": 36
        }
    },
    {
        "person": {
            "id": 10,
            "fullName": "A person # 10",
            "age": 35
        }
    }
]
```

This is my little angularJS code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Person List</h1>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="person in persons">{{person.fullName}} is {{person.age}} years old</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I'm doing person in persons. Now... "persons" is the entire json object retrieved from the $http.get in the controller.
Also since it's an array of person objects, why is not working for "person in persons"? then the person.fullName and person.age should work :(

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your object is actually nested inside each resource as `person`, so what you want is `{{person.person.fullName}}` and `{{person.person.age}}`.